# How to hide a element after a delay according to the number of characters in the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have like this `<div class='error_message'> message </div>`. This `<div>` has not a specific `width`, it depends on its text. It should be noted that its text is not the same all the time, it will change sometimes. So I want to hide it after a delay *according to the number of characters in the element.*

I can do that with a constant delay like this: *(for e.g.)*

```
$("element").delay(5000).hide(200);
```

But I need a **dynamic delay time**. I want to hide `<element>` containing a short message more faster than a `<element>` containing a long message.

For example:

```
// hide after 1 sec
<div class='error_message'> message </div>

// hide after 2 sec
<div class='error_message'> message  message </div>

// hide after 3 sec
<div class='error_message'> message  message  message </div>
```

And so on ...

Is there any solution for doing that ?

Comment: It sounds like the delay depends on number of words in the sentence instead of number of characters. right?

Comment: @Ala em, I think there is no difference, I need to a reasonable delay time...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you've accepted an answer already, I thought that I'd offer an alternative solution using plain JavaScript – if only for a sense of completion, since you tagged the question [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) – so, one possibility is the following:

```
function wordDependentFadeOut (el) {

    // retrieving the textContent of the supplied Node ('el'),
    // trimming that textContent to remove leading/trailing white-space,
    // splitting the resulting string by any remaining white-space (between words)
    // to produce an array of individual words,
    // finding the length of the resulting array and concatenating the 's' character:
    var delayInSeconds = el.textContent.trim().split(/\s+/).length + 's';

    // adding the 'fadeOut' class to the supplied node:
    el.classList.add('fadeOut');

    // setting the transition property of the node,
    // 'all' : we're transitioning all (animatable) CSS properties,
    // 'delayInSeconds' : the transition-duration,
    // 'linear' : the transition timing function,
    // 'delayInSeconds' : the transition-delay;
    // this animates between the properties defined in the CSS
    // for the '.error_message' class and those defined in the
    // (more specific) '.error_message.fadeOut' rules:
    el.style.transition = 'all ' + delayInSeconds + ' linear ' + delayInSeconds;
}


// Using Function.prototype.call() along with Array.prototype.slice to
// convert the results of document.querySelectorAll() into an Array rather
// than a NodeList; iterating over the Array using Array.prototype.forEach():
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.error_message'), 0).forEach(function (node) {
    // the first argument (here: 'node') is the array-element of the array
    // over which we're iterating.

    // calling the function, passing the current array-element (a node):
    wordDependentFadeOut(node);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6k3cuzjg/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [CSS Transitions – Working Draft (W3C)](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/).
  - [Using CSS Transitions (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
  - [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
  - [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).

Comment: It's shorter yes, because jQuery's handling the looping, delay and hiding, through the use of multiple functions called 'under the hood' as it were. Also, rather than iterating through multiple animations using a `setInterval()` I'm instead just passing a string to each element's `style` property. I haven't particularly optimised it, but I'd be surprised if it wasn't at least as efficient as the jQuery solution; remember everything jQuery does is built on native JavaScript with conditionals for cross-browser compatibility – while it looks simple on the surface it's far more complex underneath.

Comment: Can I use `display:none|block;` instead of `opacity: 0|1;` ?

Comment: No, unfortunately CSS can only transition between numerical values; to hide the elements you'd need to define an explicit `height` or `width` for the `.error_message` class and set those properties to `0` in the `.error_message.fadeOut` style rules.

Answer (score 2):

```
function countWords(string) {
  var ret = 0;
  string.replace(/(\b+)/g, function(a) { ret++; });
  return ret;
}
var len = 1000*countWords($(element).text());
$(element).delay(len).hide(200);
```

Something along those lines I suspect?

Comment: why you used `str.replace` ?

Comment: It's a very small code-footprint way to count the number of words in a string. Borrowed that code from an old snippet I had laying around.

Answer (score 1):

How about that:

```
$("element").each(function(){
  var delay = $(this).html().length * 2; 
  $(this).delay(delay).hide(200);
});
```

Comment: thanks. +1 upvote for you... just edit `* 2` and set it to `* 50`. it will be more reasonable delay time